# Updating PAX Logging configuration via ConfigurationAdmin

Tags: logging, apache-karaf, apache-felix, pax

I'm trying to setup pax-logging to dump certain logs to a specific file. I've seen that this could be achieved by means of the ConfigurationAdmin. So, I made the following:

- Inject in the blueprint a reference to the ConfigurationAdmin service
- Ask it for the configuration with PID = org.ops4j.pax.logging
- Get the current configuration and add the properties to configure an appender and a logger for my bundle
- Call Configuration.update(properties)

I can see how the file etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg gets updated and my new properties are added to it. But I see no new file created for my appender and logs from my logger are no longer added to karaf.log either. I'm able to somehow make it work again by doing a touch on the etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg, after what the new appender is created and I start to see logs written into it. This seems to be caused by felix-fileinstall, which detects the file has changed and maybe redeploys something (not sure what)

My questions are:

- Is this the proper way to add an appender programatically and dinamically? My application is intended to be distributed as a kar file with several features into it, and I want this to happen when it is started.
- Do I need to do something else other than Configuration.update(properties) to have pax-logging taking into account the changes? It seems that something changes because I do no longer see my logs after initializing my bundle, but it seems that the appender is not created.

I'm using karaf 4.1.5 and pax-logging-log4j2 1.10.1

Regards

Manuel